# tinyMCE keyup up to the ending of the first <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am trying to capture in real time what the user enters in the `.content` `textarea` and paste it to `.intro`. I tried like so, but no effect

//All this is related to tinymce, because I use tinyMCE as rich text editor for the textboxes that have `.tiny_editor` class

```
//$(".content").live("keyup", function(e) {
$(".content").keyup(function(e) { //The keyup never does its thing
    var stt=$(this).val();
    console.log('content : '+stt);
    $(".intro").text(stt);
});
```

Then, I also need it to be limited with the content of first `<p>` in the `.content` `textarea`

- `.content` `textarea`, where the user writes text

  ```
  <textarea name="content" class="tinymce content">
     <p>first paragraph</p>
     <p>second paragraph</p>
     <p>third paragraph</p>
  </textarea>
  ```
- Here is where it automatically inserted, the content between first `<p>` and `</p>` from `.content`

  ```
  <textarea name="content" class="tinymce intro">
     <p>first paragraph</p>
  </textarea>
  ```

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/xEzAq/2/

Comment: just a note - the reason you're initial javascript didn't work is because tinyMCE is creating an `<iframe />` after the `<textbox />` and that is where the content goes. Looks to me like what you want is to copy data between two `<iframe />`'s

Comment: yes, indeed... I just found out that (firebug's help) and just saw this article to http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp ... but still not sure how to tell it to copy on `keyup` from `.content` to `.intro`

Comment: I'm not too sure either - I think you'll have to call a function in the parent window which can send the data to the other iframe. Never done it before but I suppose it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you will have to check on every single keydown event if the user selection is inside the first paragraph.

In your tinymce init you need to add the setup paremeter as follows. Here is the code:

```
setup : function(ed) {

  ed.onKeydown.add(function(ed, evt) {
    var node = ed.selection.getNode();
    while (node)
    {
        if (node.nodeName == 'BODY') { node = 0; break; }
        if (node.nodeName !== 'P')    { node = node.parentNode;}
        else { break; }
    }
    if (!node) return;
    var first_node_active = $(ed.getBody()).find('p:first').get(0) == node;
    // prevent insertion of content
    if (first_node_active){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
  });

},
...
```

**Update:**
I see. In fact tinymce hides the textare and uses a contenteditable iframe for the content.
The easiest approch to solve your problem will be to use the setup tinymce configuration parameter:

```
tinyMCE.init({

  mode: 'exact',
  elements: 'content',
  ...
  setup : function(ed) {
   // handler to catch keyup events
   ed.onKeyup.add(function(ed, evt) {

      // get html content of first paragraph in the editor
      var first_node_html = $(ed.getBody()).find('p:first').html();

      // copythe html content into the textarea '.intro'
      $('.intro').text(first_node_html);

      // if intro is a tinymce editor too you will need some other code
      // here it is
      //
      // // check if intro exists as tinymce editor and make sure we are not editing in it at the moment (copying makes no sense then)
      // if (ed2 = tinymce.get('intro') && ed.id != ed2.id){
      //    ed2.setContent(first_node_html);
      // }
   });

},
...
```

Comment: what is the main text box entry? you need to be a bit clear (a demo page or fiddle is a good thing here)

Comment: is there a special point in time when the generated textarea-content shall not change anymore?

Comment: but you asked about stopping the change of that content. are you asking for the code to get the content of the first paragraph?

Comment: i still do not know exactly what you desire. what have you tried so far?

Comment: all you need to do to get the first paragraph content when setting the handler is: $(ed.getBody()).find('p:first').html();

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Please, if you're willing to, lets start this from the beginning again, check my question's update

Comment: ahhhhh!!! I just put together a fiddle to do this. Oh well, a learning experiance. Here is fiddle if interested (must view with '/show' appended): http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/ZASum/show

Comment: solved: see my edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fn6cV/7/  (you might need to push play-button of the script tab in firebug, there seems to be something buggy with the fiddle website) . just to let you know there exists a special tinymce fiddle site: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/

Comment: a fiddle or tinymce fiddle helps in most cases (1st to understand the problem, 2nd to show a solution)